# Get first three characters from array elements

Tags: arrays, c, char, uint8t

Trying to print the array elements, like below:

```c
typedef struct Info
{

UINT32      freq[8];   
                
} Info;

char FREQ[100];

sprintf(FREQ, "%u %u%c", Info->freq[0], Info->freq[1],'\0');

printf("FREQ %s",FREQ);
```

Got output is --> 931000000 345000000

How can get output like ---> 931 345

I have tried like below,

```
sprintf(FREQ, "%.3u %.3u%c", Info->freq[0], Info->[1],'\0');
```

but still getting like below output is --> 931000000 345000000

Comment: This looks like [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) ("take three characters" is one of the examples on this page). Why not divide `Info->freq[0]` and `Info->freq[1]` by `1000000`?

Comment: as shown, your output is indeterminate because you haven't initialized `Info->freq`... show that part.

Comment: Note that `sprintf` will automatically add the terminating `nul` character to its output string.

Comment: Seems like the issue is with the input, which you can verify by doing a `printf` of `Info->freq[0]`.

Comment: especially if it's a frequency, it's probably given in Hz and you want it in GHz or MHz, which means you SHOULD be dividing it with a constant.

Comment: Even with headers and `main` this does not compile because `Info` isnt a variable but a type.